# Combinatorial task about dividing a group of people into two parts.

Tags: combinatorics

We have a group of $n$ people, each of them knows at most three other persons in the group. How can one prove that the group can divided in two subgroups so that in each subgroup nobody knows more than one other person (in their subgroup!!!)? The relation is symmetric, so A knows B if and only if B knows A. Thanks in advance.

Comment: What is the source of the problem and what is your math background?

Comment: I have PhD in mathematics but unfortunately no idea how to solve it. The source is a friend who is a student.

Comment: I don't know how to solve it either.  I suspect that it involves Graph Theory.

Comment: Suppose n = 3, and every one knows everyone. How will you now divide ? The question itself seems unclear to me.

Comment: If n=3, so the group is A,B,C, then every division is ok. For example, one group is A,B and other group is C.

Comment: Is knowing assumed to b a symmetric relation in the above question?Please clarify

Comment: You ask "*nobody* knows more than one person," but here *everbody* knows more than one person ???

Comment: Is it x knows y iff y knows x?

Comment: Yes, the relation is symmetric.

Comment: Nobody knows more than one person in their subgroup, of course. In the subgroup A,B nobody can know more than one person because there is only one other person. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It appears that a solution follows from the answer to this question:

https://mathoverflow.net/questions/247734/partition-of-a-graph-into-subgraphs-with-small-maximum-degree